# How can Ubuntu detect some mobile devices that debian doesn't?

Tags: package-management, android, eclipse, debian

For example, when I plug a Samsung i770 in ubuntu and I run eclipse, the mobile device is detected and I can run my apps. But debian doesn't recognise this device. What package is included in Ubuntu that enables this? libusb maybe?

Comment: I suppose it may have something to do with Ubuntu's more lax approach to the whole "Free Software" topic. I'd be willing to bet that there's some proprietary driver that Ubuntu includes that allows it to access your device that Debian doesn't allow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question theres the solution: Theres no package that Ubuntu have that Debian doesnt to make this possible, Its all configuration.

All credit for this section goes to unforgivin512

Source: http://unforgivendevelopment.com/2011/05/20/udev-headaches-on-debian-testing-wheezy/

On the android developers website the guide for setting up a device under Ubuntu says to create the file “/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules” , this does not work in the case of Debian. What you have to do in this case is

nano /lib/udev/rules.d/91-permissions.rules as root

Find the text similar to this

```
# usbfs-like devices SUBSYSTEM==”usb”, ENV{DEVTYPE}==”usb_device”, \ MODE=”0664″
```

Then change the mode to 0666 like below

```
# usbfs-like devices SUBSYSTEM==”usb”, ENV{DEVTYPE}==”usb_device”, \ MODE=”0666“
```

This allows adb to work, however we still need to set up the device so it can be recognized. We need to create the file

nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-android.rules as root

and enter

SUBSYSTEM==”usb”, ENV{DEVTYPE}==”usb_device”, ATTRS{idVendor}==”0bb4″, MODE=”0666″

NOTE: “0bb4″ in this case is your vendors model (HTC in my case).

A full listing can be found here http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Save the file and then restart udev as root /super user

/etc/init.d/udev restart as root

All the credits to this guy:http://technologiquepark.wordpress.com/2011/09/24/preparing-debian-squeeze-for-android-development/

And as Easter egg heres my 99-andriod.rules:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0502", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0a5c", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0e79", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0b05", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="413c", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0489", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04c5", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2207", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="091e", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="109B", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="17ef", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04dd", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="054c", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0fce", MODE="0666"
```